# Discord Bot Join Message

Tags: python, discord

So I have some experience with python and discord bots but I can't seem to figure out how to make it so that when the bot joins a server for the first time it sends a message like "Hi, use !help for help" or something like that. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which text channel do you want to send the message in?

You can use [`TextChannel.send`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.TextChannel.send) to send a message in the guild, and define the method [`on_guild_join`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.on_guild_join), which will be called when a bot joins a server. Here is an example where the bots sends the message in the server's [`system_channel`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Guild.system_channel), if it exists:

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!")

@bot.event
async def on_guild_join(guild):
    if guild.system_channel:
        await guild.system_channel.send("Hi, use !help for help")
```

Here is an example where the bot will send the message in a random text channel in the server:

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from random import choice

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!")

@bot.event
async def on_guild_join(guild):
    if guild.text_channels: # If the guild has at least one text channel
        channel = choice(guild.text_channels)
        await channel.send("Hi, use !help for help")
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you. I totally forgot the guild part when I attempted this.